# Facebook: When I upload new images to an album, how do I change what photos are displayed in the wall post?

Tags: facebook

When I upload more pictures to an album, a post is created on my wall that says "... has added 90 photos to the album ...", and then has various thumbs from the album underneath. The problem is that the thumbnails are all halfway through my album, and when people click the thumbs they won't see the previous images. Is it possible to change what thumbnails are displayed in the wall post?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test 
-I uploaded 6 pictures and this is what i got 
[image]

by draggin pictures right and left you can organize them

[image]

i noticed only the 5 first ones are the ones that show up in the post
The first 2 will have a relativly larger thumnails than the others.
[image]

Comment: Ok, that's fine for when you're uploading the photos, but what if the photos have already been uploaded? Can I make a new wall post which features a subset of the photos from my album? If I just share my album it will only use the photos from the beginning.

Comment: this is what worked for me,i went to my album, add pictures , drag them up, click done.
note that the new post will use your album cover everytime you update your album.. you may have to change your "album cover".
https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/q71/s720x720/1976884_1452683274964219_687136184_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Facebook really seems to have borked this as there seems to be no way to change the photos that are featured in the timeline feed. Only way around this seems to be figure out which pictures you want and upload those to the album first in the order you want.  Re-ordering them later within Facebook will do nothing.